# Microscopic origin of magneto-optical phenomena in non-magnetic materials?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, spin-orbit

As I understand it indium antimonide (InSb) is a non-reciprocal optical material. Having non-diagonal (non-reciprocal) components in its dielectric susceptibility tensor, in the presence of a magnetic field.

Is there some kind of microscopic time-reversal symmetry breaking mechanism, so I was wondering if it had some magnetic order or at least some kind of spin-orbit coupling. But I am told that this is not the case, it is just a "gyroelectric" material. So what exactly is the microscopic theory of such materials? What is the element producing the non-reciprocity?